# sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I cover the project with tests using `pytest`.

In each application (`module`), I created the `tests folder`, inside which placed the files with the `application tests`.

In each tests folder there are `conftest fixtures` for each application.

When I run the tests separately for each application (*like `pytest apps/users`*) everything works fine.

But when I run the tests entirely for the whole project (*just `pytest`*) for the first application the `tests pass`, but then it throws the *sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed error* for other application

Example of `conftest.py`

```
import os

import pytest


TESTDB = "test.db"
TESTDB_PATH = os.path.join(basedir, TESTDB)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def app(request):
    """Session-wide test `Flask` application."""
    app = create_app("config.TestConfig")
    # Establish an application context before running the tests.
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    def teardown():
        ctx.pop()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return app


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db(app, request):
    """Session-wide test database."""
    if os.path.exists(TESTDB_PATH):
        os.unlink(TESTDB_PATH)

    def teardown():
        _db.drop_all()
        try:
            os.unlink(TESTDB_PATH)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    _db.app = app
    _db.create_all()

    permission = PermissionModel(title="can_search_articles")
    role = RoleModel(title="API User", permissions=[permission])
    tag = TagModel(name="Test tag")
    article = ArticleModel(
        title="Test article",
        legal_language="en",
        abstract="",
        state="Alaska",
        tags=[tag],
    )
    _db.session.add_all([role, permission, tag, article])
    _db.session.commit()

    user1 = UserModel(email="test@gmail.com", role_id=role.id)
    user2 = UserModel(email="test2@gmail.com")
    _db.session.add_all([user1, user2])

    # Commit the changes for the users
    _db.session.commit()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return _db


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def session(db, request):
    """Creates a new database session for a test."""
    connection = db.engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

    db.session = session

    def teardown():
        transaction.rollback()
        connection.close()
        session.remove()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return session


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def client(app):
    client = app.test_client()
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()
    yield client
    ctx.pop()
```

structure of project

```
proj/
__apps/
____articles/
______models.py, views.py, __init__.py etc
______tests/
________|__init__.py
________test_models.py
________conftest.py
____users/
______models.py, views.py, __init__.py etc
______tests/
________|__init__.py
________test_models.py
________conftest.py
______init__.py  # Here I load my models, register blueprints
__main.py  # Here I run my application
```

Comment: Just a guess: Have you tried without scope='session' in the db fixture? Maybe there is an internal confusion between the app session and the db session. If that does not help, try to rename the fixtures for each application, e.g. app_user, db_user etc. to rule out that it is just confusion in the same namespace.

Comment: where exactly exception is happen? because you set up new connection in function-scope fixture it is not seems like one of your fixtures can exit befor you use it in test. and I try to reproduce your example and run pytest in proj folder and pytest gave me an error that I have two exact the same modules test_models.py, it is interesting how you manage to run it, to run it I have to rename it. also as perfomance hint, you not need close connection in each test, just do rollback but use connection in session level.

Comment: @Sikan it doesn't work without `scope=session` (`This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception`)

Comment: @Sikan If I rename the fixtures - it's doesn't work also (`sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed`).

Comment: @IvanBryzzhin If I rename `test_models.py` to `test_models_.py` (in `users` module f.e.) it's generate this error also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have two simultaneous connections to sqlite database. Also you have two connections here, one explicit in session fixture, you open and close it by your self, and second implicit in `db` fixture (`_db.session`), probably closing not happen here. So, try use connection implicit and only once, instead db and session fixtures make only session fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def session(app):
    """Creates a new database session for a test."""
    db.app = app
    db.create_all()

    with db.engine.connect() as connection:
        with connection.begin() as transaction:
            options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
            session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

            db.session = session

            prepare_data(session)

            yield session

            transaction.rollback()
            db.drop_all()
```

here prepare_data is your data filling of new db:

```
def prepare_data(session):
    permission = PermissionModel(title="can_search_articles")
    role = RoleModel(title="API User", permissions=[permission])
    tag = TagModel(name="Test tag")
    article = ArticleModel(
        title="Test article",
        legal_language="en",
        abstract="",
        state="Alaska",
        tags=[tag],
    )
    session.add_all([role, permission, tag, article])
    session.commit()

    user1 = UserModel(email="test@gmail.com", role_id=role.id)
    user2 = UserModel(email="test2@gmail.com")
    session.add_all([user1, user2])

    # Commit the changes for the users
    session.commit()
```

because session fixture here is function-scope, in each test you will have your one database. It will be more practical dont fill database fully each time, but split this prepare_data to few separate fixtures, each for one object, and use them in tests where they exactly needed.

Comment: `You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'app' with a 'session' scoped request object, involved factories`

Comment: If I change `scope=function` to `module` it's work only for first module. For another - `sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed`

Comment: your first error `..factroies` because you also have to change scope of db fixtue to function, you can not use function-scope fixtre as parameter in more wide fixtreies, like module level or session. try change db to function and app function-scope should work

Comment: If I change `app fixture scope` and `db fixture scope` to `function` then pass only first test in first test. Another tests raise `sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed`

Comment: how many tests do you have in each module? and could you post stack trace of exception of last version?

Comment: also could you try rewrite app fixture with doc https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/  examle. create_app and app_context do under with statment and do yield instead return ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210867/discussion-between-unknown-and-ivan-bryzzhin).

Comment: How can to create object in `database` in my test? If I write `db.session.commit()` I get error `This session is in 'committed' state; no further SQL can be emitted within...`